# MySQL Cursor get specific field

Tags: mysql, cursor, field

in mysql i followed the example of using Cursor 
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cursor/

but i didn't understand how to get a specific field

in the link the Cursor define on specific column

but they said it is on all the row if it does how can i get to the field in the row?

for example if i define

```sql
DEClARE curCourseCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT 
  CourseName, 
  courseID 
FROM 
  coma.AllEmployeesCourses;
```

how can i get thous field?

in my example

thanks

Answer (score 0):

in order to handle this we just need to add verbals to the fetch section

in the example above

FETCH curCourseCursor INTO currentCourse,course_c_Id;